# Pagination: changed made on last page gone after switching back

Tags: reactjs

So I have a Semantic-ui-react Pagination Component, and have a callback function `handlePageChange`. When I make some changes on the first page, let's say select some items and highlight the items selected, and I go to the next page to select highlight more items. After going back to the previous page, my changes and highlights are all gone. Is there a way to keep the highlight after switching back to the previous visited page?

Here is my code of `handlePageChange`

```
handlePageChange = (event: SyntheticEvent<any>, data: any) => {
    const { onPageChange } = this.props;

    this.setState({
      page: data
    });
    onPageChange && onPageChange(event, data);
  };
```

Comment: When you talk about selecting, are you referring to checkboxes? Some third-party UI element you're using that supports selections? An element you created that has selection as some sort of internal state? The answer to this question depends on the kind of elements we're working with. Do you think you can post a very simplified example component of what's getting selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather, what is likely happening is that when you change pages, you unload the previous page and load up the new one. When you try to go back to a previous page, it renders it from scratch, thus none of the previous state would be preserved. (I'm going under the assumption that a selected element in the page is related to a piece of state in that page).

There's a couple solutions to this problem.

1. If the pages are light-weight enough, and there aren't many of them (I don't know what you're paginating), you can just keep them all loaded, and have the pagination buttons simply change which one is visible (toggling display:none/block). This will likely be the easiest.
2. You can have whatever element that contains the pages hold the state of the pages for you. This means that the state changes to your page will have to be sent up through callbacks (or any global state-managing system you might be using, e.g. Redux) to your pages-container. Your pages container then sets its internal state and provides these values back to its children.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem is actually that my pagination unmounts the selected components, which is a child components. Your second solution is actually what I need to do to solve the problem.